# How to load a bitmapv5 image using PIL?

Tags: python-imaging-library

I have a BMP image that I am trying to open with PIL. However, PIL is choking on this image...

It is a valid image. The image metadata is as follows:

```
sh:~/home/user$ identify -verbose badbmp.bmp
Image: badbmp.bmp
  Format: BMP (Microsoft Windows bitmap image)
  Class: DirectClass
  Geometry: 940x705+0+0
  Units: PixelsPerCentimeter
  Type: TrueColorMatte
  Endianess: Undefined
  Colorspace: RGB
  Depth: 8-bit
  Channel depth:
    red: 8-bit
    green: 8-bit
    blue: 8-bit
    alpha: 1-bit
  Channel statistics:
    Red:
      min: 7 (0.027451)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 82.3111 (0.322788)
      standard deviation: 42.3517 (0.166085)
      kurtosis: 9.21784
      skewness: 2.94025
    Green:
      min: 7 (0.027451)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 80.6959 (0.316454)
      standard deviation: 43.208 (0.169443)
      kurtosis: 8.72161
      skewness: 2.84078
    Blue:
      min: 5 (0.0196078)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 76.912 (0.301616)
      standard deviation: 45.1296 (0.176979)
      kurtosis: 7.82117
      skewness: 2.6619
    Alpha:
      min: 255 (1)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 255 (1)
      standard deviation: 0 (0)
      kurtosis: 0
      skewness: 0
  Image statistics:
    Overall:
      min: 5 (0.0196078)
      max: 255 (1)
      mean: 123.73 (0.485215)
      standard deviation: 84.6884 (0.332111)
      kurtosis: -1.16829
      skewness: 0.805031
  Alpha: rgba(52,52,52,0)   #34343400
  Rendering intent: Undefined
  Chromaticity:
    red primary: (-nan,-nan)
    green primary: (-nan,-nan)
    blue primary: (-nan,-nan)
    white point: (0,0)
  Interlace: None
  Background color: white
  Border color: rgba(223,223,223,1)
  Matte color: grey74
  Transparent color: none
  Compose: Over
  Page geometry: 940x705+0+0
  Dispose: Undefined
  Iterations: 0
  Compression: Undefined
  Orientation: Undefined
  Properties:
    date:create: 2013-05-29T13:41:17-07:00
    date:modify: 2013-05-29T13:41:17-07:00
    signature: 06a0f3720396f746fa94ee4918f3150c9bd4931ff21e9bed66d8202b4824e215
  Artifacts:
    verbose: true
  Tainted: False
  Filesize: 2.651MB
  Number pixels: 663KB
  Pixels per second: 66.27MB
  User time: 0.010u
  Elapsed time: 0:01.010
  Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2012-08-17 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
```

My code looks like this:

```
imageBytes = None
with open(fileName, 'rb') as f:
    imageBytes = f.read()

rawImage = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imageBytes))
```

When I try to run htis, I get the following:

```
  File "/home/user/__init__.py", line 149, in convert_file_adv
    rawImage = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(imageBytes))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 1965, in open
    return factory(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 91, in __init__
    self._open()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py", line 170, in _open
    self._bitmap(offset=offset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py", line 102, in _bitmap
    raise IOError("Unsupported BMP header type (%d)" % len(s))
IOError: Unsupported BMP header type (124)
```

Can someone help me understand how I can work around this issue, or fix it?